# How to random number multiple time and append different result with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get generated random numbers with different result and show them multiple times. When I click on #randomFive I want to get five times of list with different number in every list. But I get the same numbers. Here is my code.

```
$('#randomFive').click(function(){
    var arrNum = [];
    var randTime = 5;
    var numberRandom = 6;
    for(i= 0; i<numberRandom; i++){
        randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 40) + 1);
        arrNum.push(randNum);
    
    }

    for(i= 0; i<randTime; i++){
        $(".calculate-result ul").append(`<li>` + arrNum.join('+') + `</li>`);
    }
});
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, instead  of using one list you need 5 lists

Comment: @sagar1025 I added five lists instead of loop but this give me all the same number in every list. That not what I want. I want number is different in every list.

Comment: @sagar1025 this is exactly what I wanted. I really appreciate. Thank you. By the way if there any way to add "0" to number that is smaller than 10 in every list?

Comment: you can add that check in the inner loop just after this line
`randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 40) + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you mean. You want `ul` in which every `li` is a unique list of random numbers right?

This should do it.

```
$('#randomFive').click(function(){
    var arrNum = [];
    var randTime = 5;
    var numberRandom = 6;
    var x = 0, i=0;
    var listItem = [[],[],[],[],[]];
    for(x=0;x<5;x++) {
      arrNum= [];
      for(i= 0; i<numberRandom; i++) {
        randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 40) + 1);
        arrNum.push(randNum);
    }
      listItem[x].push('<li>' + arrNum.join('+') + '</li>');
    }
    listItem.forEach(function(v){
      $(".calculate-result ul").append(v);
    });
});
```

The internal loop is almost the same. I wrapped that loop in another loop to generate random numbers for each item in the `li`. The outer loop is run 5 times and will generate 5 `li`.

To generate a random number in each `li` the inner loop is used.